# how to spawn third party gui program in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode Version: 1.37

OS Version: window 1895 (No problem in mac os)

```js
// extension.ts
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  console.log('Congratulations, your extension "spawn-demo" is now active!');

  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "extension.spawnNotepad", // this work, notepad can launch
    () => {
      spawn("notepad");
    }
  );

  let disposable2 = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "extension.spawnTypora",
    () => {
      // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
      console.log('working')
      const child = spawn("Typora"); 
      child.on("error", e => {
        console.log("error", e);
      });
      child.on("close", (c, s) => {
        // c == 0, s ==null
        console.log("close", c, s);  // close immediately
      });
      child.stderr.once("data", d => {
        console.log("stderr", `${d}`);
      });
      child.stdout.once("data", d => {
        console.log("stdout", `${d}`);
      });
    }
  );
  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
  context.subscriptions.push(disposable2);
}
```

require('child_process').spawn('Typora') work well in node repl

Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: Yes